# Does Windows 7 deployed via the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit still require activation within 30 days?

Tags: windows-7, unattended, software-activation

I am learning how to use the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit and am experimenting with Windows System Image Manager.

At work, we normally use MAK keys to activate our Windows 7 installations.

I know that I can associate this key with the image used for deployment by including it in the answer file but will Windows still need to be activated online within 30 days of deployment?

If not, why not? If so, what can I do to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Whether activation occurs automatically will depend on what deployment method you're using and how your task sequence is configured. You can verify if Windows has been activated after installation by opening My Computer, clicking on System Properties, and scrolling down to the Windows Activation section.

If you're using the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) there is a task sequence step for Activate Windows. You can also add a custom command via whatever method you prefer (through unattend.xml, a task sequence step, etc.) to activate Windows using slmgr.vbs:

```
slmgr.vbs /ipk <MultipleActivationKey>
```

Comment: the slmgr.vbs command is one method. Another method could include changing the initial startup process. That would include editing the boot.wim file. Mainly the `winpeshl.exe` and/or the `winpeshl.ini` file. You can do this by inserting your own .bat/exe that executes the normal process but in addition adds a custom command. ie: the above command, add a scheduled task for activation, etc... more info on modifying boot.wim, install.wim, unattended.xml is available here > http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-usb-drive-that-will-install-vista-win7-and-server-2008

Comment: The problem with this method is that it would count against the activation count for our MAK, whereas deploying a pre-activated Windows 7 image to multiple desktops would not. Is there any way to somehow make the image pre-activated so that it would not count against our MAK activation count?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MAK activation but isn't there a reason why you have have a limited activation count? The only issue in it affecting your activation count I can see is needing to deploy it, again, on a computer that has already used an activation. Regardless, if there's a way around this I'm unsure (using above suggestions) and all I can offer is imaging an activated computer. Then deploying after it's been decommissioned. I've used a similar method to this involving Virtual Images that I either deploy to another computer or import to a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Are you in an active directory environment? If so, why aren't you using KMS? MAK should really only be used for computers that have to be off the domain for some reason.